# jQuery - Replace Text / HTML for Dynamically created elements from external js file

Tags: jquery

How can I replace the text/html for **dynamically created elements from HTML page through External .js file**

**For Eg:**

I want to replace "`Hello`" text to "`Welcome`"... I am doing this by following from `external.js` file

```
$("h5").text("Welcome");
```

**Original content is coming from HTML page  along with dynamically created text and I want to replace this from external .js file**

> **[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/0ny5nryt/1/)**

*Below HTML and code from index.html*

**HTML**

```
<div class="replaceMe"><h5>Hello</h5></div>
<a href="#" class="addNew">Add New</a>
```

**Script inside the HTML page**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".addNew").on("click", function(){
    $(".replaceMe").append('<h5>Hello</h5>');
  });

});
```

**external.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".replaceMe h5").text("Welcome");

});
```

Comment: You'll just need to run the replacement code inside the `click` event, too.

Comment: You can't change the content of something that doesn't exist, and there's no way to delegate that either, you just have to wait until the element actually exists before you can change it, and as noted in the comment above, that happens inside the click handler.

Comment: Hi **@gpmcadam** Thanks for quick turnaround... I have tried it is working great if the code is coming from same page... 

But, I want to do the same from External js file, where original code is coming from HTML page (do not have control to change it)... I want to replace all <h5> content of this page from external js file..

Comment: Do you want to replace hello to welcome when click on add  new anchor? at the time when you are creating dynamically div ?

Comment: Yes **@shiva chauhan**.. but I want to do this from external js file. where as dynamic content is getting created from index.html page :(

Comment: Please can you tell me that code of adding h5 is in external.js or in same html page ?

Comment: dynamic creating is happening in index.html and changing text code has to happen from external js file

Comment: Try removing `$(document).ready(function(){})` wrapper surrounding `$(".replaceMe h5").text("Welcome");` at "external.js"

Comment: Hi **@guest271314**.. Tried with no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace text specific h5 element text.

Using ID

```
//Create Tag with "ID"
function appendTag(tag, id, text){
    try{
        $(".replaceMe").append('<'+tag+' id="'+id+'">'>'+text+''</'+tag+'>');
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }finally{
        tag = null;
        id = null;
        text = null;
    }
}

function replaceText(tag, id, text){
    try{
        //ID should be unique
        //$(tag+' #'+id).text(text);
        $('#'+id).text(text);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }finally{
        tag = null;
        id = null;
        text = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your external code in a function , so you'll be able to call it each time your script inside your page is called.
Dispatch an event in your script in your HTML page. Catch this event in your external file with document.addEventListener. Call the function that replace "Hello" with "Welcome".

Or more simply, just call your external function in your main script when you need it.